# procedural label texture

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, procedural

how is possible make a label design all with nodes with the shader editor in Blender (basic rectangles shapes and letter)?
I add the final result done with Illustrator.
[image]

Comment: Typography in nodes is really involved :p

Comment: how is involved?

Comment: If you have an image texture of the text, that's simple, but if you're asking how to create the letters with math functions in nodes, it's a lot of work

Comment: oh i know but is just this the question, how can do it with only the math nodes...
this was a great suggest for the development team https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/cbfbbc/

Comment: Someone asked for pointers about that some months ago. They have put videos about it on their youtube channel. Look for the very first videos https://www.youtube.com/c/DrBlender/videos

Comment: If you're using Cycles, you could try to find a way to call some external font rendering library with [OSL](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/osl.html).

Comment: @WillChen no, for this project i use eevee

Comment: i have find this, but look like hard to use https://www.blendswap.com/blend/24437